# Number of pairwise non isomorphic 2-connected graph with no $K_4^-$ minor

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism, graph-connectivity, graph-minors

I had this question in my graph theory exam today, and I'm pretty sure I answered it wrong.

We define $K_4^-$ as $K_4$ with one less edge. Find the number of pairwise non isomorphic graphs $G$, such that $|V(G)| = 20$, $G$ is 2-connected and $G$ contains no $K_4^-$ minor.

What I found is that there are no such graphs.

My approach was that a 2-connected graph should always contain at least 1 cycle, and we can see that $K_4^-$ is basically just 2 cycles of length 3 sharing a common edge.

And since a cycle of length 6 or more can always be contracted in a way to create a $K_4^-$ graph (just contract some edges until you get 2 cycles sharing an edge), then we need to have all the cycles in the graph to be of length 5 or less, and no 2 cycles should share a common edge (if they do we can easily form $K_4^-$). Now, we also need to have more than 1 cycle in the graph, if not $G$ will not be 2-connected. And we can easily see that if we have 2 or more cycles (I made some case by case analysis on cycles of length 5 or less), we can always contract edges to make those 2 cycles "close" to each other until they have a common edge, and hence  a $K_4^-$.

I'm not too good in graph theory, and I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious (probably somewhere in my assumptions), because this problem seems too easy. Maybe I'm missing a fundamental fact about 2-connectedness, I don't know.

Comment: How do you contract a $C_6$ to get a $K_4^-$? If you contract one edge of the $C_6$, you get a $C_5$. If you contract another edge, you get a $C_4$, which is missing an edge from being $K_4^-$.

Comment: OMG I finally understand. For some reason I was just joining any 2 vertex and calling it contracting (whether there is an edge between the vertives or not). I knew my mistake was dumb, but not this dumb. I should probably not be doing math, let alone doing a math test when I haven't slept for 35h...

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you!

Comment: What's even worse is that I've been thinking about that for a couple hours, and was going crazy because I couldn't figure it out, and I had to post here just to get some peace of mind. Damn this is embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should get upset. You were close to solving the problem. Here is your reasoning in my version.

Choose an arbitrary cycle $C$ in the graph $G$.
If all vertices of the cycle $C$ have degree $2$, it is easy to see that $G=C$.

Let $u\in V(C)$ and degree $u$ be greater than $2$. Let an edge $e=uv\in E(C)$ and an edge $e'=uw\notin E(C)$.

If $w\in V(C)$, then the edge $e'=uw$ is a chord of the cycle $C$ and then
$K_4^-$ can be obtained from $C\cup\{e'\}$ by contracting edges from $C$.

Let $w\notin V(C)$.
Since the graph $G$ is $2$-connected, there exists a cycle $C'$ containing edges $e$ and $e'$.

Moving along the cycle $C'$ in the direction from vertex $u$ to vertex $w$ we find the first common vertex $x\neq u$ of cycles $C$ and $C'$ (of course, it is possible that $x=v$).

Consider the path $P=\{uw\ldots x\}$ along the cycle $C'$. This path has exactly two vertices $u$ and $x$ in common with the cycle $C$.

Obviously, we can obtain $K_4^-$ by contracting the edges of $C\cup P$.

Thus it is clear that any $2$-connected $K_4^-$-minor-free graph is a cycle.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Yeah I'm not that upset anymore, but I could have solved it if only I noticed that I was contracting edges in a completely wrong way

Comment: Okay. I would like to point out that my answer omits one point. The point is that cycles $C$ and $C'$ can have many common vertices and edges. 
First we must consider the case when two vertices of cycle $C$ are connected by a path that has no other common points with $C$. 
Then there are two cases: 1) these vertices are neighbors of cycle $C$; 2) they are not neighbors. 
 I will think it over and modify my answer if you do not mind.

Comment: I don't see how having many common vertices and edges would be a problem. We only need to remove all vertices and edges not in $C \cup C'$, and then start contracting all edge around our edge $e$. The other common edges and vertices wouldn't matter (unless I'm missing something again). Maybe I'll understand after you edit your answer.

Comment: @MoonlessNightss I have edited my answer. I think it's more accurate now.

Comment: Okay so you expended a bit on both cases, I would have only said what you said in your previous answer being "we can contract all edges until we get $K_4^-$", but now it's more formal. Also for the first case I would have taken $C$ to be the smallest cycle to not have any cords (it's a bit cleaner IMO). Nonetheless thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes, I thought about the shortest cycle as well, but it seemed to me that the way in the answer is a bit easier. 
 Good luck to you in mastering graph theory.

Comment: Thank you, and have a nice day!